# How to build a nested route with Django REST Framework?

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, nested-resources

I want to build a simple API and picked up [Django REST Framework (DRF)](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/). I want to [minimize path nesting](https://github.com/interagent/http-api-design#minimize-path-nesting) as [Tom Christie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/596689/tom-christie) (the author of DRF) pointed out to me.

There are two models: *Article* and *Comment*.
For these I want to build the following API paths (with *create [C]*, *read [R]* and *update [U]* access):

```
/                      [R]
/articles/             [R]
/articles/:id/         [R]
/articles/:id/comments [R]
/comments/             [CRU]
/comments/:id          [R]
```

models.py:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=140, blank=False)
    recorded_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=False)
    modified_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


class Comment(models.Model):
    message = models.CharField(max_length=140, blank=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    article = models.ForeignKey('Article', default=1, related_name='article')
```

serializers.py:

```
class ArticleSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Article


class CommentSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
```

views.py:

```
class ArticleViewSet(mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                     mixins.ListModelMixin,
                     viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer


class CommentViewSet(mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                     mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                     mixins.ListModelMixin,
                     viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    queryset = Comment.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CommentSerializer
```

urls.py:

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'articles', ArticleViewSet)
router.register(r'comments', CommentViewSet)


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
)
```

The path at root level work:

```
/                      [R]
/articles/             [R]
/articles/:id/         [R]
/comments/             [CRU]
/comments/:id          [R]
```

However the nested path returns 404.

```
/articles/:id/comments [R]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need something like this on your `ArticleViewSet`...

```
@detail_route(methods=['get'])
def comments(self, request, pk=None):
    article = self.get_object()
    comments = article.comment_set.all()
    serializer = CommentSerializer(comments)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: The path `articles/:id/comments` renders when I remove `related_name='article'` and use `serializer = CommentSerializer(comments, context={'request': request}, many=True)`. Now only the breadcrumb states the wrong name: `Article` instead `Comment`.

Comment: "Now only the breadcrumb states the wrong name: Article instead Comment." That's going to stay the same way unless you want to have a dig into overriding the template (I wouldn't especially recommend that') - I'd probably just live with it at that point.

Comment: Now that you telling I remember that I read somewhere that detail views do not render the correct object title. Thank you.